# Installing Oracle Database Software 19c on openSUSE LEAP 15.3

Tags: oracle, opensuse, oracle19c

I try to install Oracle Database Software. When i unzip package i try to
launched runInstaller as root of course. However terminal show me error like:

> ERROR: Unable to verify the graphical display setup. This application requires X display. Make sure that xdpyinfo exist under PATH variable.
> ERROR: You must not be logged in as root to run this tool.

How to fix it and install Oracle 19c?
Additionaly I use openSuse Leap 15.3 KDE Plasma on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Don't tell me, you tried to run the install via sudo? Don't, it does not setup xauth. Rather, su to root and run it that way.

Comment: But that still doesn't work .

Comment: Really? Worked here. What if you try `xterm`? What if you do `export DISPLAY=:0` and try again. You are doing this locally, aren't you?

Comment: in fact, now i don't unserstand what i should do. I still learn linux. In xterm i have still te same errors

Comment: Start by telling us the topology of your system and how you are connecting.

Comment: Basicly is fresh system on VirtualBox i didn't change antything. only unpacking software form oracle

Comment: And you are running a GUI within VBox? If not install the KDE desktop.

Comment: When I installing system i check KDE Plasma. In my VB GUI is visibly, included.

Comment: Logout of the gui and login as root, then try.

Comment: If you are having this much trouble, I really suggest you use opensuse and an ordinary and get used to how it all hangs together. You are going to have to install quite a few extra packages before Oracle will install fully and properly.

Answer (score 0):

Safe yourself a lot of time and start with the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/index.html

It will tell you to create a user that is going to be the owner of the software and also the user that you use to install the software with.

This manual is pretty useful. If you have a problem setting up your x windows environment, go for a silent install via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

> "launched runInstaller as root of course."

And that is exactly what the fine [Installation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/index.html) says *not* to do.

> I use openSuse Leap 15.3

And that is ***not*** listed as a supported OS in the Installation Guide.  It *does* list two versions of SUSE Linux Enterprise Server.  But since you are building your wn system under VBox, why not use Oracle Linux?

And since you are using VBox, you will need to insure that your network adapter(s) are properly configured.  I've created scores of VBox linux machines over the years.  One of my guiding principles is that I want to treat them exactly as I would a physical server that lives behind a locked door, in a  lights-out data center.  That means I do not rely on the VM console, and instead access the machine with the same desktop tools as I do that server in the data center.  And to make that work I have to have one of the network adapters on the VM configured as HOSTONLY.  (in addition to the default adapter that is configured for NAT (Network Address Transalation).  When first installing and configuring the OS, I configure the HOSTONLY adapter with a fixed IP address.  With that I can then access the VM with an ssh client installed on the host machine. I use PuTTY.  For the GUI, I configure my ssh (PuTTY) connection for x-11 host forwarding, and run XMING on the host desktop.  With that, a GUI app launched from the ssh client will present on the host desktop.

You can read more deatil [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/configure-the-virtualbox-network-2/).

But regardless of all other considerations, if you want to successfully install Oracle Database, you *must* read the appropriate installation guide.  *Especially* all of the installation prerequisites.

-- Edit
Just to clarify, My comments about configuring network adapter, use of ssh client, etc, are to address your specific reported error about "Unable to verify the graphical display setup"